# Codeigniter Pagination directs me to 'about:blank#blocked'

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter Pagination doesnt work, the URL changes to 'about:blank#blocked'.

I'm fairly new at php frameworks and codeigniter. I tried to read the documentation but I don't seem to see the problem.

**Controller:**

```
class Listing extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index() {


    //Get Total Records Count
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("cities");
    if (!empty($_GET['cityFilter'])) {
        $this->db->like('city_name', $_GET['cityFilter']);
    }
    $cityRecordsCount = $this->db->get();

    $totalRecords = $cityRecordsCount->num_rows();
    $limit = 10;

    if (!empty($_GET['cityFilter'])) {
        $config["base_url"] = base_url('Listing/index?cityFilter=' . $_GET['cityFilter']);
    } else {
        $config["base_url"] = base_url('Listing/index?cityFilter=');
    }

    $config["total_rows"] = $totalRecords;
    $config["per_page"] = $limit;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
    $config['num_links'] = 2;
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<li class="active"><a>';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $links = explode('&nbsp;', $str_links);

    $offset = 0;
    if (!empty($_GET['per_page'])) {
        $pageNo = $_GET['per_page'];
        $offset = ($pageNo - 1) * $limit;
    }

    //Get actual result from all records with pagination
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("cities");
    if (!empty($_GET['cityFilter'])) {
        $this->db->like('city_name', $_GET['cityFilter']);
    }
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $cityRecords = $this->db->get();
    $this->load->view('listCities', array(
        'totalResult' => $totalRecords,
        'results' => $cityRecords->result(),
        'links' => $links
    ));
}
```

}

**HTML**

```
        <div id="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-12">
                <h1>Pagination With Search.</h1>
                <p>A demo for Codeigniter 2.X framework</p>
                <br>
                <form action="" method="GET">
                    <div class="input-group pull-right">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search For City" 
                               name="cityFilter" value="<?php
                               if (!empty($_GET['cityFilter'])) {
                                   echo $_GET['cityFilter'];
                               }
                               ?>">

                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
                        </span>
                    </div> 
                </form>


                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>City Name</th>
                            <th>City State</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($results as $o) {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $o->city_id; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $o->city_name; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $o->city_state; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>

                    </tfoot>
                </table>
                <ul class="pagination pull-right">
                    <!-- Show pagination links -->
                    <?php
                        foreach ($links as $link) {
                            echo "<li>" . $link . "</li>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It shows a blank page and the URL changes to 'about:blank#blocked'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: same thing here